# How to fix OutOfMemoryError exception in android?

Tags: android, gradle, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I am new to android development in fact.
I have an android app dealing with large length of list and each list item has bitmap thumbnail.
The app load the entire database so it is clearly not efficient.
But for now I can't code it again efficiently because it will spend much time and also can't use `try and catch` because I don't know where this exception will occur.
I just want to know another simple solution such as `android:largeHeap="true"`, `dexOption` in app.gradle or `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in gradle.property.

I tried them but nothing is improved.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you are using to display the list? RecyclerView or regular ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryError with large bitmaps is a known issue in Android.

You need to handle it in your source code. Tweaking the Manifest file settings is not the solution.

Here an example how to deal with large bitmaps.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Libraries like Picasso can make your job more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use library like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: I already used Glide.